# One-sample test for proportion

Tags: python

I want to do "One-sample test for proportion" with Python. I found this document [one sample proportion ztest example](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.stats.proportion.proportions_ztest.html) but I don't understand how to use it. For example, what are count and nobs. In the 2 examples, example1 gives single number for count and nobs, however, example2 gives 2 numbers.

For result, I'd like to know the p-value that the event happen rate is higher than 60%

Example1

```
>>> count = 5
>>> nobs = 83
>>> value = .05
>>> stat, pval = proportions_ztest(count, nobs, value)
>>> print('{0:0.3f}'.format(pval))
0.695
```

Example2

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from statsmodels.stats.proportion import proportions_ztest
>>> count = np.array([5, 12])
>>> nobs = np.array([83, 99])
>>> stat, pval = proportions_ztest(counts, nobs)
>>> print('{0:0.3f}'.format(pval))
0.159
```

My data looks like this

```
Yes No
1   0
1   0
1   0
0   1
0   1
1   0
1   0
0   1
0   1
0   1
0   1
0   1
```

Can you help explain how to use it and give some examples?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In case of example 1:

`nobs` is the total number of trials, i.e. the number of rows in your list.

`count` is the number of successful trials, i.e. the number of `Yes` events in your list.

`value` is the proportion to test against, i.e. `0.6` based on your question text.

The null hypothesis here is that the single sample given by these values was drawn from a distribution with proportion equal to the specified `value`.

In case of example 2:

There are two independent samples, the first entry of the `nobs` and `count` vectors represent the first sample, the second ones the second sample. `value` is then omitted and the null hypothesis will be that the two samples have equal true proportion.

Comment: Thank you!  I tried `count = 6726
nobs = 592458
value = 0.6407
stat, pval = proportions_ztest(count, nobs, value)
print('{0:0.3f}'.format(pval))`  but the output is  0.000

Comment: yes, this is the correct result. It means, that if the true success proportion was `0.6407`, then the probability of seeing `6726` out of `592458` events being successful, is practically zero. The sample proportion `6726/592458 = 0.0114` is way off of `0.6407`

Comment: I see thank you. but I want to print out p-value, it's not zero it's just too small for python to print out. is there anyway I can print result like `< 2.22e-16 ***`  ?

Comment: You would need to catch the case manually and print this instead of zero. This value is just around the smallest precision where standard floating point calculations still make sense.

Comment: You can use `rom decimal import Decimal
print('{0:.2E}'.format(Decimal(pval))) ` for printing out scientific notation

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by user10605163 is correct for the question asked.

However, as the `proportions_ztest` from statsmodel uses classical statistical method of using normal distribution to approximate binomial distribution, the p-value you get from `proportions_ztest` is different from what you get if you calculate it from first principle.

In this age of computing, it seems that using normal distribution to approximate binomial is no longer necessary, especially for such small trial sizes.

You can use a bit of combinatorics to calculate the probability space, or you can simulate many sets of trials and get the p-value directly without any test statistics.

Answer (score -1):

For the explanation of how to use [this document](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.stats.proportion.proportions_ztest.html) is in comments.
For printing out p-value in scientific notation:

```
from decimal import Decimal
print('{0:.2E}'.format(Decimal(pval)))
```